# Boost.Asio sometimes doesn't notify about TCP keep-alive timeout

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio, keep-alive

I have TCP socket with enabled keep-alive and configured keep-alive timeouts to some reasonable values. When I unplug the connection, `async_read` handler is invoked with an error, but not always. It seems like it doesn't work when I run another `io_service` in another thread. Can another `io_service` interfere somehow with the local one?

I've checked by Wireshark that keep-alive messages works as expected - it detects disconnection properly.

Comment: Without a reproducer this question doesn't really fly. You could contact the mailing list with a generic out-of-context question like that.